# Cannot signUp with login module created with firebase and got the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null' from the client sidee

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, use-ref

For creating user authentication in react I used firebase authentication module,So I setup the firebase config file and created the authentication file and created the signup module for the creating the signup page in "react-app" folder but when I `{ currentUser.email}` in my signup module I got the error message `'TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null'` in the client side. This error occurs when I coded ```{ currentUser.email}`` in **signup.js** file in line number **36**.

So I am giving up the three files, these 3 files are responsible for the creation of signup page

**1.SignUp.js File**

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useAuth  } from '../contexts/AuthContext'  

const SignUp = () => {
    const emailRef = useRef()
    const passwordRef = useRef()
    const passwordConfirmRef = useRef()
    const { Signup, currentUser } = useAuth()
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

   async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        if(passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value){
            return setError('Password do not match')
        }

        try {
            setError('')
            setLoading(true)
            await Signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
        } catch {
            setError('Failed to create an account')
        }

        setLoading(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Sign Up</h2>
                { currentUser.email}
                {error && <Alert variant='danger'>{error}</Alert>}
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group id="email">
                        <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef}
                        required />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group id="password">
                        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef}
                        required />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
                        <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordConfirmRef}
                        required />
                    </Form.Group> <br></br>
                    <Button  disabled={loading} type="submit" className="w-100" type="submit">Sign Up</Button>
                </Form>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
            <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2"> 
                Already have an account? Log In
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default SignUp
```

**2. AuthContext.js File**

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    function signup(email,password){
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    }

        useEffect(() => {
           const unsubscribe =  auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user)
            setLoading(false)
            })

            return unsubscribe
        }, [])
   
    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup
    }
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**3. App.js file**

```
import React from 'react'
//import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import Signup from './Screens/SignUp'
import Header from './components/Header'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { AuthProvider } from './contexts/AuthContext'
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Header />
    <AuthProvider>
    <Container className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
    
    <div className='w-100' style={{ maxWidth: '400px'}}>
    <Signup />
    </div>
    </Container>
    </AuthProvider>
    
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error I got on the client side is like this:

[image]

Comment: `currentUser` is null. check it

Comment: Can you give me the snippet where do I change the line.

Answer (score 0):

If no user is logged in then `currentUser` is null. You should check if a user is logged in yourself.

```jsx
<h2 className="text-center mb-4">Sign Up</h2>
{ currentUser ? currentUser.email : "No user"}
```

Try refactoring your code as shown above. If no user is logged in, it'll show "No user".

Comment: Yes now the code worked but I am now not able to signup I am getting the error **Failed to create the account** in the client side.

Comment: @AbhijeetKujur What error? Can you update your question with complete details?